# Implementing scan disc scheduling using c, c++ or java

Tags: java, c++, c, operating-system

learning system's programming,how can I implement scan disk scheduling algorithm using C, C++ or java. The requirements are for the piece of code to actually access the disk handles. Below is an example of the code I have been working on, but the problem it is merely a simulation of what is actually taking place when scan disk algorithm is running. The header position and the input data are simply the values which I as  user is inserting into the program. I want it to be able to actually read the current header position, and en queue the requests and implement scan disk scheduling or any other scheduling algorithm

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
#define max 15
#define cymax 249

int i,j,req,ttl_tracks=0,cp,np,cposn,nposn;
int cyposn[max],temp;

void input()
{
 do
 {
  clreol();
  printf("\n Enter the current header position : ");
  scanf("%d",&cposn);
  /*cposn current cylinder position which in this case is the same
  as the current header position*/
 }while(cposn>cymax || cposn <=0);
 printf("\n Enter the %d I/O Requests : ",req);
 cyposn[0] = cposn;
 for(i=1;i<=req;i++)     /*This for loop helps to store the different requests
 inputs in the array of cylinder positions cyposn: Note that the initial array
 cyposn stores the value of the initial header postion  and that is why the for
 loop begins with 1
 */
  scanf("%d",&cyposn[i]);



}

void SCAN()        /*function for the scanning schedule*/
{
int tmp = cp;  /*the tmp integer is used for swapping values, from the current
cylinder position to the next*/
 int ind = 0;
 for(i=0;i<=req;i++)/*this outer loops counts the number of requests*/
 {
  for(j=0;j<req-i;j++)   /*this inner loop walks through different values in the
  cylinder array which would later become sorted */
  {
   if(cyposn[j] > cyposn[j+1])/*compares the two values previous position
   and the next position, if the previous is greater than the next position, the
   positions are swapped, taking the next position tobecome the current position
   a situation which would always ensure that the current position will become
   as small as possible:
   HENCE THE HANDLE WILL MOVE TO THE LEFT
   */
   {
    temp = cyposn[j];
    cyposn[j] = cyposn[j+1];
    cyposn[j+1] = temp;
   }
  }
 }
 cp=0;  /*when  the loop finishes untill it finds the most minimal value:
 the handle is assigned to position '0' making the current position to be zero*/
 do
 {
  if(cyposn[cp] == cposn)
   break;    /*if it reaches the possible maximum cylinder value
   it breaks else it increments the values*/
  cp++;
 }while(cp!=req);


 printf("\nS.No.  Current Position    Next Position   Displacement \n");
 printf("---------------------------------------------------------- \n\n");
 i=0;

 cposn = cyposn[cp];
 do
 {
  if(ind == 0)
  {
   if(cp == 0)
   { nposn = 0; ind = 1; }
   else
    nposn = cyposn[--cp];
  }
  else
  {
   if(cp == 0)
    cp = tmp;
   nposn = cyposn[++cp];
  }


  printf(" %d\t\t%d\t\t%d\t\t%d\n",++i,cposn,nposn,abs(cposn-nposn));
  ttl_tracks += (abs(cposn-nposn));
  cposn = nposn;
 }while(nposn!=cyposn[req]);
 printf("---------------------------------------------------------- \n\n");
 printf(" Total Tracks Displaced : %d",ttl_tracks);
}

void main()
{
 do
 {
  clrscr();
  printf("\n Enter the number of requests : ");
  scanf("%d",&req);
 }while(req>max || req <=0);
 input();
 SCAN();
 getch();
}
```

Comment: To do systems programming, you will need to specify the specific system you are working on.  The answer will be different for OSX, Windows, etc.

Comment: Okay I am working on Windows, to be more specifically windows 7. I have read that windows operating systems tends to keep their kernel locked for programmers, so if its not possible to implement in windows I can even work with Linux specifically ubuntu 14. I simply need to know how it works and how I myself can write a code which actually implement the scan disk scheduling algorithm

Comment: You know, I don't think modern hard disks allow manual control of the heads. If they do, you're probably better off getting a book and a lot of disks to destroy while you learn.

Comment: Hahahaa, name of the book please, I am willing to take the risk

Comment: I once read that by using certain C++, Java or even C libraries one can actually access the disk handle, and hence lead to behave the way they will it to... Hence implementing the scan disk scheduling algorithm is possible in that sense

Comment: ANY RELEVANT MATERIAL WOULD REALLY HELP, EVEN OF THE SIMPLY THE CODE, WITHOUT ANY NEED OF RUNNING IT

Comment: I recommend you search SuperUser.StackExchange.com for more information.  This is not a C, C++ or Java programming issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send commands to the hard drive.  The protocol depends on your hard drive.

Check these out:
http://www.ata-atapi.com/pata.html
http://www.t13.org/documents/uploadeddocuments/docs2006/d1699r3f-ata8-acs.pdf

I suggest you research SATA, PATA and ATAPI protocols.  Also search for "Petzold writing device drivers".

Comment: I have also conducted a research of my own, and I have found that using a c library stdlib. In C a group of functions which allows you to access the memory. The issue here is how to implement disc scheduling algorithms, It is in my understanding that most operating systems are written in C, what  I need is to get the practical of it, on  where the disc scheduling algorithms where implemented at the operating system level, if there is  a C code or a C++ or java code which could do that like the way malloc functions in stdlib access the memory it would be quite helpful.